# Handling/destroying threads when switching between activities

Tags: android, thread-safety

I have two activities in my application. The `MainActivity` has a thread which establishes a connection to the server as shown below :-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private Socket socket;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 8020;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.36";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
            new Thread(new ServerThread()).start();
    }
    public void onClickon(View view) {
    try{

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
            true);
    out.println("0"); 
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
     private void newActivity(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LockActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     }
     class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
    }
```

When the user clicks on a button to go send a message to a server the `onClickOn()` function is called.
Now when the user wants to go to the new activity, the `newActivity()` function is called.

The code for new activity is as follows.

```
public class NewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
public void buttonOKclicked(View v)
    {
        String msg=Integer.toString(foo);
        Intent intent = new Intent(LockActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("keyMessage", msg);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    }
```

When the user is in the `NewActivity`,he clicks the button which calls the `buttonOkclicked()`  which goes back to the `MainActivity`.

When the user gets back to the `MainActivity`, the application is not able to make connection back to the server.

How should i solve this?

Can I kill the `ServerThread`, before creating the `NewActivity, so that when the user gets back to the`MainActivity`, a new thread could be started?